# Unable to load \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration() class with Doctrine 2 classloader in cli-config.php file when using the doctrine CLI

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, integrate

I followed the steps in the following article in order to integrate Zend Framework 1.11 and Doctrine 2:

http://jeboy25.blogspot.com/2010/08/doctrine-2-and-zend-framework-110.html

And I have 3 questions about the article:

1-In the "SchemaToolClass" section i don't understand why the author includes schema_tool.php at the bottom of ZendProject/public/index.php file after :
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();

2-when i execute the command "php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create" i have the following error message in the command line: 
HP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Library/WebServer/Documents/carlending/application/tools/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /Library/WebServer/Documents/carlending/application/tools/doctrine:7
PHP   3. require() /Library/WebServer/Documents/carlending/application/tools/doctrine.php:41
PHP   4. Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader->loadClass($className = *uninitialized*)
the error occurs in the cli-config.php file at the line '$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();'

3-Can you explain why the author puts the doctrine generated proxies and models inside the domain folder. Isn't it better that they reside in the models folder like any other model class.
Sometimes i also see some programmers using a 'generated' folder inside models.

If you managed to make a working integration of Zend 1.x and Doctrine i would be very happy if you could also send me a working project that would very helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After reading "Obtaining the EntityManager" section in http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html

I think you need the following three lines to bootstrap:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
require_once 'Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php';
Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work a few weeks ago, here's my code. Doctrine 2 is really nice :)

### In my bootstrap

```
/**
 * Initialize auto loader of Doctrine
 *
 * @return Doctrine_Manager
 */
protected function _initDoctrine() {
    $this->bootstrap('autoload');

    require_once('Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php');

    // Create the doctrine autoloader and remove it from the spl autoload stack (it adds itself)
    require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
    $doctrineAutoloader = array(new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader(), 'loadClass');
    //$doctrineAutoloader->register();
    spl_autoload_unregister($doctrineAutoloader);

    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

    // Push the doctrine autoloader to load for the Doctrine\ namespace
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader($doctrineAutoloader, 'Doctrine');

    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', realpath(__DIR__ . '/models/'), 'loadClass');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($classLoader, 'loadClass'), 'Entities');

    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../library/Doctrine/'), 'loadClass');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($classLoader, 'loadClass'), 'Symfony');

    $doctrineConfig = $this->getOption('doctrine');
    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    $driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../configs/mappings/yaml');
    //$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($doctrineConfig['path']['entities']);
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('App\Proxies');

    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => $doctrineConfig['conn']['driv'],
        'user' => $doctrineConfig['conn']['user'],
        'password' => $doctrineConfig['conn']['pass'],
        'dbname' => $doctrineConfig['conn']['dbname'],
        'host' => $doctrineConfig['conn']['host']
    );

    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->entitymanager = $em;

    return $em;
}
```

### Schema etc

I use yaml as you seen above, I haven't looked through the tutorial but I've used the command line tool that works like a charm, my doctrine.php (located in APPLICATION/bin):

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../configs/application.ini'
);

$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');


require_once __DIR__ . '/../Bootstrap.php';

$em = $application->getBootstrap()->getResource('doctrine');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em, APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/mappings")
));

\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

You first have to generate your entities:

- Generate all the models without deleting, creates also annotations - 
  ./doctrine orm:generate-entities ~/Public/my_app/application/models/ --regenerate-entities 0 --generate-annotations 1

then generate your schema
./doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
or
./doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql

the proxies are not really a part of your models, it's just used by Doctrine internally so I've put it as a separate entity from the models folder but I guess it doesn't really matter:
./doctrine orm:generate-proxies ~/Public/my_app/proxies/

Remember to add write permissions to the proxies for apache group.

Hmm... guess I didn't quite explain Jeboy's solution but perhaps my code helps you get started, it took me a while but once it's up and running it works like a charm :) 
PS Don't forget the "namespace Entities;" in each of your models (it should be generated automatically)